# ActiveMQ Artemis master slave pair HA, split brain problem

Tags: activemq-artemis

I've got two ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 servers. They are on different machines in a cloud environment using master - slave HA config. When the master fails the slave become active and without a problem accepting messages from producers, but also throwing this error:

```
2021-08-16 16:42:17,796 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212007: connector.create or connectorFactory.createConnector should never throw an exception, implementation is badly behaved, but we will deal with it anyway.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
    at java.base/java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:224) [java.base:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:851) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:843) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:825) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1090) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1152) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1371) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:945) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:834) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.reconnectSessions(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:779) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.failoverOrReconnect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:638) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.handleConnectionFailure(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:525) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.access$600(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:74) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingFailureListener.connectionFailed(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1282) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.protocol.AbstractRemotingConnection.callFailureListeners(AbstractRemotingConnection.java:78) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.fail(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:220) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.protocol.AbstractRemotingConnection.fail(AbstractRemotingConnection.java:221) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$CloseRunnable.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1050) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [java.base:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
```

When I checked master and slave pair I don't know why but everytime they are getting same nodeId. I tried to clear all data folder for both of them and run both again, but everytime nodeId was same.

When I run master again getting these errors...

**master side**

```
     _        _               _
    / \  ____| |_  ___ __  __(_) _____
   / _ \|  _ \ __|/ _ \  \/  | |/  __/
  / ___ \ | \/ |_/  __/ |\/| | |\___ \
 /_/   \_\|   \__\____|_|  |_|_|/___ /
 Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0


Aug 16, 2021 4:42:16 PM java.lang.System$LoggerFinder lambda$accessProvider$0
WARNING: Failed to instantiate LoggerFinder provider; Using default.
2021-08-16 16:42:16,695 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
2021-08-16 16:42:16,736 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2021-08-16 16:42:17,062 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212007: connector.create or connectorFactory.createConnector should never throw an exception, implementation is badly behaved, but we will deal with it anyway.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
    at java.base/java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:224) [java.base:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:851) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:843) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:825) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1090) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1139) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1371) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:945) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:834) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:252) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:268) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:688) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.SharedNothingLiveActivation$NodeIdListener.isActive(SharedNothingLiveActivation.java:444) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.SharedNothingLiveActivation$NodeIdListener.nodeUP(SharedNothingLiveActivation.java:422) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.Topology$1.run(Topology.java:289) [artemis-core-client-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [java.base:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]

2021-08-16 16:42:17,134 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2021-08-16 16:42:17,168 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1,073,741,824
2021-08-16 16:42:17,233 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2021-08-16 16:42:17,235 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2021-08-16 16:42:17,236 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2021-08-16 16:42:17,236 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2021-08-16 16:42:17,237 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2021-08-16 16:42:17,238 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2021-08-16 16:42:17,803 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
2021-08-16 16:42:17,804 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
2021-08-16 16:42:17,811 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2021-08-16 16:42:17,811 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
2021-08-16 16:42:17,812 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address hello supporting [ANYCAST]
2021-08-16 16:42:17,812 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue hello on address hello
2021-08-16 16:42:18,095 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at <master-ip>:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2021-08-16 16:42:18,099 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5445 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]
2021-08-16 16:42:18,102 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5672 for protocols [AMQP]
2021-08-16 16:42:18,104 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:1883 for protocols [MQTT]
2021-08-16 16:42:18,111 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61613 for protocols [STOMP]
2021-08-16 16:42:18,112 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2021-08-16 16:42:18,113 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.17.0 [<master-ip>, nodeID=e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1]
2021-08-16 16:42:18,145 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222294:
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
There is a possible split brain on nodeID e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id = e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=-1&host=null, b=null], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2021-08-16 16:42:18,381 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222294:
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
There is a possible split brain on nodeID e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id = e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=-1&host=null, b=null], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2021-08-16 16:42:18,478 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2021-08-16 16:42:18,525 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2021-08-16 16:42:18,841 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2021-08-16 16:42:18,904 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2021-08-16 16:42:18,907 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.11.0
2021-08-16 16:42:18,915 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2021-08-16 16:42:18,938 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2021-08-16 16:42:18,944 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/var/lib/mybroker/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2021-08-16 16:42:19,081 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8161
2021-08-16 16:42:19,082 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console/jolokia
2021-08-16 16:42:19,082 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console
2021-08-16 16:42:19,089 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222294:
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
There is a possible split brain on nodeID e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id = e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=-1&host=null, b=null], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2021-08-16 16:42:20,089 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222294:
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
There is a possible split brain on nodeID e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id = e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=-1&host=null, b=null], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2021-08-16 16:42:56,807 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2021-08-16 16:42:58,238 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.keycloak.KeycloakServlet] Keycloak integration is disabled
```

**slave side**

```
2021-08-16 16:42:18,142 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222294:
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
There is a possible split brain on nodeID e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id = e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=23-88-60-180, b=null], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2021-08-16 16:42:18,407 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222294:
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
There is a possible split brain on nodeID e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id = e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=23-88-60-180, b=null], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2021-08-16 16:42:19,087 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222294:
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
There is a possible split brain on nodeID e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id = e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=23-88-60-180, b=null], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2021-08-16 16:42:20,087 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222294:
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
There is a possible split brain on nodeID e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id = e15d46ae-fe99-11eb-b371-960000d265b1, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=23-88-60-180, b=null], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

**master config**:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>master-node</name>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <acceptors>

         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://<master-ip>:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</acceptor> -->
      </acceptors>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="hello">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="hello"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>

      <cluster-user>myuser</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>mypassword</cluster-password>

      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <master>
               <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            </master>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-backup-connector">tcp://<slave-ip>:61616</connector>
         <connector name="artemis">tcp://<master-ip>:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>netty-backup-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>

   </core>
</configuration>
```

**slave config**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>hetzner-slave</name>

      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://<slave-ip>:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://<slave-ip>:61616</acceptor> -->
      </acceptors>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="hello">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="hello"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>

      <cluster-user>myuser</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>mypassword</cluster-password>

      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <slave>
               <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
               <max-saved-replicated-journals-size>0</max-saved-replicated-journals-size>
            </slave>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-live-connector">tcp://<master-ip>:61616</connector>
         <connector name="artemis">tcp://<slave-ip>::61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
         <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>netty-live-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

I think the problem occurs because both nodes are getting same id, but I could't find a way to give them different nodeID's.

Comment: A master and slave are *supposed* to share the same node ID.

Comment: Have you gotten this working on your local machine using different ports for each broker? That should be pretty simple to test and validate that everything is working properly before introducing the complexity of a cloud environment.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I found that the problem is related with version.
Same config in artemis 2.18 is working without problem, but artemis 2.17 causes above problems.